# node.js multiple callbacks/callback serial execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, callback, promise

So I am trying to create a node.js-mongoose app that exposes certain RESTful API endpoints. Here's a high-level structure:

```
index.js
|
models
|-- user.js
|-- keys.js
controllers
|-- user.controller.js
|-- keys.controller.js
routes
|-- user.routes.js
|-- keys.routes.js
```

Here's the pattern that I am following for each of the individual pieces:

**myModel.js (Model file)**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const mySchema = new Schema({
  id: { type: 'String', required: true, unique: true },
});
let MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel', mySchema);
export default MyModel;
```

**my.controller.js (controller file)**

```
import MyModel from '../models/myModel';
const MyController = {};

// Add a new document
MyController.addNewDocument = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // validate req

    // save to database
    await newDocument.save((err, saved) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send(err);
      } else {
        return res.status(201).json({ document: saved });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Unexpected error in addNewDocument method');
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }
};

export default MyController;
```

**my.routes.js (router file)**

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import MyController from '../controllers/my.controller';
const router = new Router();

// Add a new document
router.post('/documents', (req, res) => {
  MyController.addNewDocument(req, res);
});

export default router;
```

So I have these CRUD operations (controllers and routes) in place for both `users` and `keys`. The behavior required is that every time I create a new user, a new set of keys should be generated with the business logic in the function that is exposed by the controller file for key.

Question:
How do I execute them one after the other? What should be the right pattern?

Things I have tried:

1. Callback hell
2. calling the other endpoints from within the controller function with res.redirect, etc.

Things I explores:

1. Promises
2. Multiple callbacks

But I am still unsure of what would be the right manner to achieve the above behavior.

Comment: Your async function `addNewDocument` in `my.controller.js` is awaiting what?
And is addNewDocument is meant to be awaited then why are you not awaiting that in `my.routes.js` ?

Comment: @SivcanSingh - Sure. the `addNewDocument` funciton is doing db operations (updated the comment '//save'). 

I put the code to show the pattern that I am following with the routes, models and controllers. Not to be taken as the exact code. 

And my question is on an entirely different topic, I think.

Comment: Why do you use an `async` function without any `await` keyword?

Comment: @mathakoot The community will only help you if the code they read is right. :) 
I was only here for this. Even if you're doing the db operation, you need to 'await' that operation somewhere in this function itself. Else no point in writing async.

Comment: @SivcanSingh - My point was that I am not trying to debug my code. I just wanted to show the pattern that I am following with my controller and router functons. But if it helps, let me update it.

Comment: @Bergi - added.

Comment: @mathakoot I don't think `newDocument.save()` returns a promise when you pass a callback

Answer (score 2):

Mongoose has pre and post save hooks. [docs here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

You can use them to avoid callbacks and keep logic separate.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const keySchema = new Schema({
   user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
   key: { type: 'String', required: true, unique: true },
});

const userSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
});

userSchema.post('save', (newUser) => {
    // generate key
    new Key({
        user: newUser._id,
        key: '1234567890'
    }).save();

});


let User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
let Key = mongoose.model('Key', keySchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I use for queues uses promises.

```js
const promiseQueue = Promise.resolve();

function patchFile(request, response) {
 promiseQueue
  .then(() => updateFile(request))
  .then(v => respondValid(v, response))
  .catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
    respondError("Error patching resource", response);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best possible way to avoid callback hell is by using few methods offered by async along with promises.

```
async.waterfall([
  function(callback){
    .....
    callback(null, res)
  }
 ],
 function(error, result){
 .....
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Deferred

Above link shows the easiest way to use promises

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but to me it looks like you're using a callback and an `await` at the same time. Why not just `await` and handle things normally?

```
// Add a new document
router.post('/documents', async (req, res) => {
  let doc = await MyController.addNewDocument(req.body);
  res.json(doc);
});
```

...

```
MyController.addNewDocument = (doc) => {

  // Validate doc.
  ...

  // Save doc (this returns a promise).
  return MyModel.create(doc);

};
```

I'm missing a try/catch in the async function (use your imagination!). One other thing to point out, and this is just my opinion – you may end up regretting passing the full `req` and `res` objects to your controllers. See how I've only passed in `req.body`. This ensures the controller only has the responsibilities associated with the document (or whatever it's job is) and doesn't know anything about the HTTP transaction and other things that are well over its head.